# Do smithing improvements depend on original stats?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Certain information in the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Smithing_(Skyrim)) suggest that improvements from smithing do not depend on the original stats.

For example, at a certain level, improving a piece of armor will give it +100 armor, regardless of whether the armor is a daedric armor with 30 base armor or a steel boot with 4 base armor. (Assume you have all the relevant perks. Numbers are made up.)

Is this true?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't trust the wiki?

Comment: The wiki does not explicitly state this. I only inferred this from certain information in the wiki.

Comment: It is also really counterintuitive that the value of the item is based on the original item, but that the cost isn't.

Comment: +1, this is so surprising and counter-intuitive that confirming it with other gamers seems like a reasonable step. I had no idea this was the case, but know now because you asked the question.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely agree that it is an extremely weird system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smithing provides a flat bonus to the armor that does not depend on the original armor value. So improving Daedric Armor to Legendary Quality, and improving Steel Armor to Legendary Quality will give them both +20 to armor. The Daedric armor will still be better, because it started out with higher armor to begin with.

See Table from [this section](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Smithing_(Skyrim)#Improvement) of the wiki, and is supported by another [Skyrim wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing#Item_Quality).

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure quoting the wiki will convince someone who doesn't trust the wiki.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Thats fair, but from their comment "wiki does not explicitly state this" I figured I would point it out explicitly.